# PermissionError at /download/

Tags: django, python-3.x

when i try to download the file it says PermissionError at /download/

**views.py**

```
def download(request, path):
   file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
   if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
        return response
   raise Http404
```

**urls.py**

```
re_path(r'^download/(?P<path>.*)$', views.download)
```

**in html templates**

```
<a href="/download">Download</a>
```

i have tried everything such as moved project folder to another directory or run it as admin etc but it says

```
    Internal Server Error: /download/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\jurnal-6LxuXEYu\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\jurnal-6LxuXEYu\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\.virtualenvs\jurnal-6LxuXEYu\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zako5\PycharmProjects\jurnal\jurnal_app\views.py", line 40, in download
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Zako5\\PycharmProjects\\jurnal\\media/'
[27/Mar/2019 10:56:09] "GET /download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 66483
```

any help would be appreciated) this problem has been pissing me off for a week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your path is empty as such it is trying to open `MEDIA_ROOT` which is a directory

say your directory structure is as follows:

```
-media root
  - 1.xlsx
```

Then you update tour html as

```
<a href="/download/1.xlsx">Download</a>
```

so your path variable becomes 1.xlsx

Comment: here is my media root dir 'MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')'

Comment: please can you show me how to open? I opened the path if exists above code

Comment: @JibinMathews great thanks a lot) at last it worked but one more thing please can you tell me file type can only be pdf or ppt, doc. and there are more files now i specified only 1.xlsx how can I specify in the url and restrict file type for only pdf doc and ppt. Thank you beforehand

Comment: @coder in view you can split the path with `.` and check if it matches your array of valid types